# What does this message from AVFoundation mean

Tags: macos, avfoundation, osx-mountain-lion

I've set up a routine to record parts of the screen. I follow [this Q@A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1740/_index.html). It works fine. However, I get this message on the console:

```
AVF info: Successfully connected to the Intel plugin, offline Gen6 
AVF encoder info: AVF_SetParam kAVF_Encoder1_ProfileLevelUpdateParam, reset profile_level from 100:50 to 77:31
```

What does the second one mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is noisy debug output from AV Foundation setting up the h264 encoder (triggered behind the scenes by your screen recording logic). In this case most likely hardware accelerated through an AV Foundation Intel plugin. The second line means that the h264 encoding profile and/or level was changed - which also probably happens automatically given the output encoding that you requested for the screen recording.